# Javascript - have forEach wait for promise to resolve before reiterating

Tags: javascript, node.js

NOTE: This is a Express.js app.

I have an array of `users` that I want to input into a DB:

```
const usersArray = //an array of user objects
```

And to input each user into the DB, I am using `forEach` to iterate over each object. But the issue is that there is a `promise` involved when inputting users into the DB, which will either return success (the user has been inserted into the DB), or return failure (for some reason, the user was not inserted into the DB).

The problem is that `forEach` doesn't actually wait to see how the promise resolves before iterating over the next object. How do I get `forEach` to wait for a promise to resolve before continuing?

The reason I want it structured this way: because once all the users have been inserted successfully into the DB, I want to be able to send a response to the front-end saying that, indeed, all the users have been inserted into the DB.

```
usersArray.forEach((user, index)=> {
    insertUserIntoDB(user).then(response => {
        console.log('User added to db!');
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
    if (usersArray.length === index + 1) {
       /*This code should only execute once all the Users have been inserted into the DB*/
       res.send('success');
    }
    if (usersArray.length !== index + 1) {
        //At THIS point, I want forEach to resume
    }
});
```

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: You should not insert your users into the database one-by-one. Instead, insert the whole array in a single database request. Otherwise you will face serious performance issues.

Comment: node version 8.3.0

Comment: `Promise.all` is your friend.